# Got Error In angular material, can't recognized the material

Tags: angular

I using angular 13 an already installed the angular material an imported the material in app.module.ts, here's the code

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
// Material Navigation
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
// Material Layout
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
// Material Buttons & Indicators
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
// Material Popups & Modals
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
// Material Data tables
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { TopNavComponent } from './Layout/top-nav/top-nav.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  schemas:[
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "studentadminportal2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

but when i want to use in app.component.html, i got an error

**'mat-slider' is not a known element:**
**1. If 'mat-slider' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.**
**2. If 'mat-slider' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ng**

did i miss something here? sorry i am newbie in angular

Comment: Changes look ok. Can you re-run application and see

Comment: ohhh its run correctly, but is it okay if the error still appear in vscode?

Comment: Your code looks correct so Maybe any extension you have added in VSCode is giving this error randomly. Try to disable extensions related to Angular and see

Comment: okay thanks a lot sir